# Vue how to ensure async requests from both components have succeeded?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2

I have 2 components that each perform an AJAX requests with axios:

```
axios.get(this.ajaxUrl)
    .then((response) => {
```

Both of these components are hooked up to a Vuex store and I need to perform an action that ensure both async requests have succeeded.

To do this I need to have something in place which waits for both successful AJAX requests and only fires at that point.

I is not hard to do this for a single AJAX requests, I could set a property in my store like `ajaxSuccess` which defaults to `false`. When that property is being set to `true` I could simply use a watcher to respond to it and perform my event.

I have used this construct before and it works fine. How would I do this for multiple AJAX requests though?

Comment: This seems like an architecture problem. You could bypass the issue if you managed your requests in your store actions.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? Not to be rude but this comment does not really benefit me that much otherwise.

Comment: It's hard to give more concrete feedback on your logic given you've showed none of it in your question.

Comment: create a new action that perform them both and use `axios.all`